# Yeoman still lists uninstalled generators

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I wanted to upgrade a generator, so I hit `npm update -g generator-jhipster`, I have node installed via `nvm` using `v6.9.2.`

Even after removing *and reinstalling* `nvm`, `npm`, `yo`, I still see the same generators!?

```
~/Documents/workspace/jhipster$ which yo
/Users/jordanbaucke/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin/yo
~/Documents/workspace/jhipster$ which npm
/Users/jordanbaucke/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin/npm
~/Documents/workspace/jhipster$ which node
/Users/jordanbaucke/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.2/bin/node
~/Documents/workspace/jhipster$ yo --generators
```

All looks good!

```
~/Documents/workspace/jhipster$ yo --generators
Available Generators:

  jhipster
    cloudfoundry
    entity
    heroku
    languages
    openshift
    service
    aws
    client
    docker-compose
    import-jdl
    info
    kubernetes
    modules
    server
    upgrade
  webapp

  jasmine

  mocha
```

But... none of these should be installed:

```
~/Documents/workspace/jhipster$ npm list -g --depth=0 | grep 'generator'
~/Documents/workspace/jhipster$
```

Where is `yo` finding these ***generators and how do I remove them???***

Already tried:

`npm uninstall -g yo`
`rm -rf ~/.nvm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have multiple npm installed on your computer. This means that there's multiple global node modules folders.

You can run `DEBUG=yeoman:* yo` to get some insight into where those globally installed packages are.

As for the multi npm instances, you should delete the duplicated one.

Comment: Thank you! I found multiple `node_modules` folders ( `~/node_modules`, `~/workspace/node_modules` ) removing these corrected my issue! Thanks!